# Odd artifacts showing up in Javascript element

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have two buttons in an html page moving a line around a circle, I want there to always only be one line but when the buttons are pressed enough for the line to be on the bottom half of the circle moving clockwise extra lines appear
the actual words are the buttons because I am using icons for the buttons on the actual page, setting it as a button made for more editing.

since I was told I have too much code I removed the 3 lines of css there was so even though the words dont change color or anything on the page they still can be clicked to move the arm

```js
var pos = 0; //global variable
var inc = 0.1;
function clockwise() {
  pos -= inc;
  drawCircle();
}
function counter() {
  pos += inc;
  drawCircle();
}
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = canvas.height / 2;
ctx.translate(radius, radius);
radius = radius * 0.9;
setInterval(drawCircle, 0);
function drawCircle() {
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fill();
  drawHand(ctx, pos, radius * 0.9, radius * 0.02);
}
function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = width;
  ctx.lineCap = "round";
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.rotate(pos);
  ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.rotate(-pos);
}
```

```html
<p><b1 id="left" onclick="clockwise()">counter-clockwise</b1></p>                 
<p><b3 id="right" onclick="counter()">clockwise</b3></p>
<canvas id="canvas" width="240" height="240" style="background-color:transparent"></canvas>
```

Comment: Please restrict your post to the parts that matter: if your JS isn't working, the python part is irrelevant, so don't include it: all it does is make it harder for people to help. Also, if the problem is with what you're drawing, then none of that HTML, except for the canvas element, is relevant. Just put a runnable snippet in your post that shows off the problem, and _only_ the problem, as per the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask). Right now you've included tons of text and code that has nothing to do with the problem you're trying to get help on.

Comment: And to that end, also give the [mcve] article a read, which helps you turn "your entire setup" into "only the parts that matter".

Comment: I included the the python because as I said in the part about what I tried the interactive elements didnt work at all without that, so if someone tried to recreate what I did that would be needed, furthermore, the two p elements that are in the html are the buttons, so they need to be include I will remove some more but there is very little other than what I needed to recreate what was happening on my page

Comment: I managed to get the program working with just the HTML and javascript, I am still getting the same artifacts though, I could really use some actual help.

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as a `<b1>` or `<b3>` element. Also you'll want to adapt your example code a bit to fit the runnable snippet's height, which is 200px (any more, and people need to start using scrollbars, which isn't great). Having said that, it just looks like you're not clearing the canvas properly, you're only filling an arc, which isn't enough. Remember to use `clearRect` or, alternatively, `fillRect` with your canvas dimensions.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I did the b1 and b3 on purpose after seeing how the part of my code that sends data to the server was selecting its elements just to see what would happen and everything works fine, even when I load it on my phone it looks like when I reduce the size of the screen on my computer, so it all seems to work correctly. I'm curious though, do you know of any problems this could cause?

Comment: they're treated as unknown elements with nothing backing them, so: just don't use tags that don't exist. They do nothing, as in they literally do the same as if you didn't have them there, so just don't have them there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arc drawing is also a path.

Change this:

```
function drawCircle() {
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fill();
  drawHand(ctx, pos, radius * 0.9, radius * 0.02);
}
```

To this:

```
function drawCircle() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fill();
  drawHand(ctx, pos, radius * 0.9, radius * 0.02);
}
```

As @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans said, you should also clear the drawing area everytime before starting to draw a new frame. You can also save the context state before rotating it and after you do what you want, restore the previous state. Doing so, you will not need to rotate back the same amount of radians. I changed your increment to degrees too. I rewrote your code, take a look:

```js
var pos = 0;
var inc = 30;

function clockwise() {
  pos -= inc * Math.PI / 180.0;
}

function counter() {
  pos += inc * Math.PI / 180.0;
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = canvas.height / 2;
ctx.translate(radius, radius);
radius = radius * 0.9;

setInterval(drawCircle, 0);

function drawCircle() {

  ctx.clearRect( -radius-10, -radius-10, radius*2+10, radius*2+10 );

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fill();

  drawHand(pos, radius * 0.9, radius * 0.02);

}

function drawHand(pos, length, width) {

  ctx.save();
  ctx.rotate(pos);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = width;
  ctx.lineCap = "round";
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.restore();

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body style="background-color: #009688">
    <canvas
      id="canvas"
      width="240"
      height="240"
      style="background-color: transparent"
    ></canvas>
    <p><button id="left" onclick="clockwise()">counter-clockwise</button></p>
    <p><button id="right" onclick="counter()">clockwise</button></p>
  </body>
</html>
```